# How can I connect a garden hose to a kitchen sink?

Tags: hose, spigot

We were gifted a baby pool so that our baby can play outside on our patio.  However, we don't have an outdoor spigot that we can use to connect a hose to.  The patio is right off the kitchen and near a half bath, so I'm wondering if there's something I can do?  Can I connect a hose to a sink somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Sinks don't typically have a direct connection, but you should have a shut off valve under the sink that you should shut off and stack a couple of fittings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to get a hose thread in the kitchen is with a "portable dishwasher" (or clothes washer, but less commonly sold that way) adapter. Do a search for that term, you'll find them - any well-stocked hardware store should have them, as well.

The typical format is a device that screws in place of your aerator on the faucet, which has a "quick-connect" - the hose thread is on one quick connect, your original aerator or a new aerator is on the other quick connect, so you can easily swap them (intended, as you roll your portable dishwasher over to connect it - but you can use the hose thread for any purpose - mine has a Jet carboy and bottlewasher on it.)

Comment: All waterbed filling kits have **sink to garden hose adapters.**